# How to access Textblock in DataTemplate in ribbon in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, ribbon

I am new using WPF I search whole day but I did not find any answers that I can apply it to my application.

I have a Menu ribbon but I want to set the title of the ribbon through my `.cs` code. My problem is I cannot access the textblock inside my `<Ribbon.TitleTemplate>`.

**Here's my XAML code**

```
                <Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon">
                    <Ribbon.TitleTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <TextBlock x:Name="FrontPageTitle" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding ElementName=RibbonWindow, Path=ActualWidth}">
                                <TextBlock.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="MintCream " BlurRadius="10"   />
                                </TextBlock.Effect>
                            </TextBlock> 
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Ribbon.TitleTemplate>
                    <Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
                        <RibbonButton SmallImageSource="pack://application:,,,/MYSEP;component/Images/window.png" />
                    </Ribbon.HelpPaneContent>
                    <Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
                        <RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
                            <RibbonButton x:Name="QATButton1" 
                                         SmallImageSource="pack://application:,,,/MYSEP;component/Images/window.png" />
                            <RibbonButton x:Name="QATButton2" 
                                         SmallImageSource="pack://application:,,,/MYSEP;component/Images/window.png" />
                        </RibbonQuickAccessToolBar>
                    </Ribbon.QuickAccessToolBar>
                </Ribbon>
```

**And here's my C# code**

```
public FrontPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            mypSepProject = (Project)App.Current.Properties["myp_projects"];

            FrontPageTitle.Text = mypSepProject.ProjectName;
            CreateRecentMenu();
            SetTreeViewMenu();
            ShowChildeWindow("Process Data");
        }
```

But `FrontPageTitle` does not exist in the current page. But when I put the `textblock` outside the `DataTemplate`, it can read the `FrontPageTitle` already.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use data binding. For this purpose, add a `DepndencyProperty` to the `FrontPage` class e.g., `Title` and bind the `TextBlock.Text` of the `Ribbon.TitleTemplate` to it.
In case `FrontPage` is a `Page`, you can use the inherited `Page.Title` property instead:

**FrontPage.xaml.cs**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "Title",
  typeof(string),
  typeof(FrontPage),
  new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

public string Title
{
  get => (string) GetValue(FrontPage.TitleProperty);
  set => SetValue(FrontPage.TitleProperty, value);
}

public FrontPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  mypSepProject = (Project)App.Current.Properties["myp_projects"];

  this.Title = mypSepProject.ProjectName;
}
```

**FrontPage.xaml**

```
<Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon">
  <Ribbon.TitleTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock x:Name="FrontPageTitle" 
                 Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=FrontPage}, Path=Title}"" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </Ribbon.TitleTemplate>
</Ribbon>
```

Comment: I've got this error sir ```System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Failed to create a 'AncestorType' from the text 'FrontPage'.' Line number '28' and line position '64'.'
```

Comment: It says that ```FrontPage is not supported in a WPF project```

Comment: You have to fully qualify every type using the namespace. I just left it to reduce confusion. Usually Visual Studio will assist you. You can click on the bulb when hovering over the code portion that is marked by squiggles. The qualified type looks something like this: `myNamespace:FrontPage`.

Comment: This is a little bit confused sir because this is my first WPF project. Thank you so much for your answer sir.

Comment: I think by default the generated namespace alias is `local`. So try: `AncestorType=local:FrontPage`.

Comment: You should read [Microsoft Docs: XAML Namespaces and Namespace Mapping for WPF XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml). It's fundamental knowledge. It's required. And easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I am half an hour late to the party :-)

Add this to your `FrontPageTitle` `TextBlock`:

```
Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Ribbon}}, Path=Title}"
```

And in the code you can just do:

```
Ribbon.Title = "ABC";
```